# What's the correct way of installing jdk on linux

Tags: linux, java

I am running the debian based Crunchbang linux system and i want to install the **Oracle JDK** (not openjdk) on my system.

I've spent some time to google for it, but i was not able to find a clear description of how to install (and configure) it.
So here are my questions:

WHERE is the correct/best location to install the downloaded JDK? (most people prefer something like `usr/lib/jvm`. why?

when i have installed the jvm (i.e. copied the content of the `jdk<version>.tar.gz` file to the chosen location, i have to setup my system to refer to the jdk.

here I can use for example: `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" \
"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk<version>/bin/java" 1`.
i have to do the same with `javac` right?

finally i have to set the JAVA_HOME variable by adding the lines:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk<version>/
export JAVA_HOME
```

to the `.bashrc` file.

But the problem: This way i always have to update my alternatives whenever i upgrade my jdk right? How can i solve this?
Can anybody give a clear description how to install the jdk on linux systems in a clever and correct way?

thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install and stay up to date with the latest Oracle Java 7 and all you have to do is manually add the PPA repository to the Software Sources.

From http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html:

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a     /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
exit
```

For Ubuntu, http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html. With this, I've managed to installed JDK on my ubuntu server.

Comment: thank you, this worked like charm! just for information, how would i uninstall java this way?

Comment: why would I be blocked from: Err http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy/main Sources       
  403  Forbidden

Comment: FOR JDK8 - Just do install oracle-java8-installer instead of java7

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Open Applicaction>> Accessories>> Terminal

Step 2: Type commandline as below...

```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Step 3: Type commandline as below...

```
  apt-cache search jdk
```

(Note: openjdk-6-jdk is symbolically used here you can choose jdk version as per your requirment.)

How to set "Environment Variables" for "Open jdk" in Ubuntu(Linux)?

Step 4: For "JAVA_HOME" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

```
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration you should use your path as per your installation.)

Step 5: For "PATH" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

```
  export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin
```

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration you should use your path as per your installation.)

Step 6: Check for "open jdk" installation, just type command in "Terminal" as shown below java

Comment: Isn't there a repository for JDK 7? JDK 6 reches its and end-of-life this month.

Comment: thank you, but i do not want to install 'openjdk' but the official ORACLE jdk (Sun) (which i have to download from their website, since it is not in my repository)

Comment: export PATH screws up my PATH variable.

Comment: It should be `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 3):

**In 2020 here is how we roll!**

**NB: This will also work for Command Line on Linux Systems.**

Kudos to this dude [here](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-oracle-jdk-in-ubuntu.html)

**Step 1:**
Download the latest JDK(jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz) from this official site.
using this

```
 wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

because we are installing remotely if not just download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

**Step 2:**
Open the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and enter the following command.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
```

**Step 3:**
Enter the following command to change the directory.

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

**Step 4:**
Extract the jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz file in that directory using this command.

```
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

*According to this command, the JDK filename is jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz and which is located in the ~/Downloads folder. If your downloaded file is in any other location, change the command according to your path.*

**Step 5:**
Enter the following command to open the environment variables file.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

In the opened file, add the following bin folders to the existing PATH variable. (in my case the file was empty so i just add the content and saved).

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/jre/bin"
J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231"
J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/jre"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231"
DERBY_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/db"
```

*This is how your file will look after modifying...*

Save the changes and close the gedit.

**Step 7:**
Enter the following commands to inform the system about the Java's location. Depending on your JDK version, the paths can be different.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java" 0

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/javac" 0

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/javac
```

**Step 8:**
To verify the setup enter the following commands and make sure that they print the location of java and javac as you have provided in the previous step.

```
update-alternatives --list java

update-alternatives --list javac
```

**Step 9:**
Restart the computer (or just log-out and login) and open the terminal again. (I dint have to do this because step 10 already came through)

**Step 10:**
Enter the following command.

```
java -version
```

**Step 11:**
Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just make a symlink `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk` that points to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk<version>`. Then all you have to do after updating the JDK is update the symlink to point to the new location.

Comment: PS: If available for your distribution, you should just add a repository that pulls in Oracle JDK like @Linn sugested.

Comment: Thank you, i think i will go this way :) just to clarify: i have to refer to this symlink in  update-alternatives, as well as in the bashrc file and so on? where should i place the symlink? and when i want to use other commands than java or javac (e.g. javaw) i have to run the respective update-alternatives command right?

Comment: You create the symlink in `/usr/lib/jvm`. cd to that directory and run `ln -s jdk<version> jdk` as root (or use `sudo` if on ubuntu or a similar distribution). You then run update-alternatives and refer to the new symlink.